# Combination: Selecting at least two cards, at least one from two non-exclusive sets.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

I'm trying to figure out probabilities of certain hands for a game I've been considering.  An example is the probability of having a card that is an Ace or King and a card that is a Heart or a Diamond, but it can't be just a single Ace of Diamonds alone.  There must be a card from each set.  It can be an Ace of Diamonds and an Ace of Hearts, though.  I.e. one fulfilling the rank and one fulfilling the suit.

I can figure the combinations that fulfill either set.  Assuming a 7 card hand:

Ace, King: ${52 \choose 7} - {52-4*2 \choose 7}$

Heart or Diamond: ${52 \choose 7} - {52-13*2 \choose 7}$

My issue is figuring at least one from each set, excluding ones where there is only one match, total, common between both sets.

I tried finding the combinations of the exclusive sets, the union with two, the union and each exclusive, but the non-exclusiveness and overlapping I've not been able to figure out.  I've gone through my probability and statistics books and tried searching the web, but the examples I could find were all for exclusive poker hands, etc.  I'm frustrated because I'm convinced it is so simple and yet I can't see it.

I'm also trying to figure out the probabilities of this success in various different sized hands to see what a reasonable hand size is.  I also have other success sets in mind, like the one above but also requiring say at least one Queen, etc., but I figure I can glean how to figure that if I knew how to think this one through the logic.

Thank you for considering this.

EDIT: re true blue anil, AH with AD would be a success.  As long as there is at least one unique card fulfilling each set, it is a success.

EDIT: My current line of attack is dividing the space into unique groups of hands: no good cards, 1+ cards in Set A but none in B, 1+ cards in set B but none in A, 1+ cards in A-B and 1+ cards in B-A, 1 card in A intersecting B but none outside of it, etc.  Then just add up the success hands.  I don't know if that will work, but I'm at a loss.

EDIT: See the accepted answer below, but wanted to post what I had figured as well for posterity.

I broke the space into four sets.

**A** $[2, .., Q] \oplus [\heartsuit, \diamondsuit]^T$

**B** $[A, K] \oplus [\spadesuit, \clubsuit]^T$

**C** $[A, K] \oplus [\heartsuit, \diamondsuit]^T$

**D** $[2, ..., Q] \oplus [\spadesuit, \clubsuit]^T$

Good hands are:

**1**) two or more **C**

$${A + B + C + D \choose 7} - \left( {A + B + D \choose 7 } + {C \choose 1} \times {A + B + D \choose 6} \right) $$

I count the number of ways to get only hands with no card in **C** at all and hands with one of the **C** cards and 6 cards from anything but **C**.  I subtract this from the total hands, and I have the hands with two or more **C** cards.

**2**) one **C** and any from **A** or **B**

$${C \choose 1} \times \left({A + B + D \choose 6} - {D \choose 6} \right)$$

Here, I count the number of hands having one of the **C** cards with the rest of the hand selected from and remaining cards not in **C**, but excluding hands that are only made of cards from **D** (leaving subsets with at least one **A** or **B**)

**3**) none from **C** and at least one from **A** and **B** each

$${A+B+D \choose 7} - \left( {A + D \choose 7} + {B + D \choose 7} \right)  + {D \choose 7}$$

Here I create my sub set of hands from all hands that don't contain **C**.  I then remove any hands that do not contain a **B** and any hands that do not contain an **A**.  I have to add back the same number of hands that contain only cards from **D** because I subtracted those hands in removing the **A** and **B** exclusions twice.

The accepted answer is much more concise, but I wanted to also show my work in case it helped someone somehow on a search of this.

Comment: "...excluding ones where there is only one match, total, common between both sets.", Does this mean that if you get $AH$ alone it's not ok, but two such, e.g. $AH$ and $AD$ is ok ?

Comment: Yes, as long as there is a card for each set, it's ok.  AH with AD is a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling aces and kings "high" cards and others "low", divide the cards as follows:

$A_1: 4\;$ high cards from hearts or diamonds

$A_2: 4\;$ high cards from spades or clubs

$B_1: 22\;$ low cards from hearts or diamonds

$B_2: 22\;$ low cards from spades or clubs

We shall count hands that **don't** fulfill both criteria, and then find the complement:

All $7$ from $(B_1\cup B_2)\cup(A_2\cup B_2): \binom{44}7 +\binom{26}7 -\binom{22}7$

$1$ card from $A_1$ and $6$ from $B_2:\binom{4}1\binom{22}6$

Now take the complement, $$\text{thus number of good hands}\; =\binom{52}7 - \left[\binom{44}7 + \binom{26}7 - \binom{22}{7} + \binom41\binom{22}6\right]$$

Comment: I think this allows for both cards to only come from one of the two sets, while none came from the other.  There must be a at least one unique card from set A and at least one unique card from set B.  i.e. two Hearts and no Ace or King is a failing case.

Comment: I have recast the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out a less sophisticated way and this gives to same results so I feel like there's a solid solution here.

Comment: Good for you :)